# Django generic ListView. When I wanted to add second get() method to the class AdListView(OwnerListView). It fails

Tags: listview, django-views, get

Program replies that its impossible to use second get() method in the same ListView.
In the first get I was taking information for "favorite" buttons.
For the second get I need to pull information for the search button.
How it is possible to overrwite it?

```
    class AdListView(OwnerListView):
    model = Ad
    # By convention:
    template_name = "ads/ad_list.html"
    def get(self, request) :
        ad_list = Ad.objects.all()
        favorites = list()
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            # rows = [{'id': 2}, {'id': 4} ... ]  (A list of rows)
            rows = request.user.favorite_ads.values('id')
            # favorites = [2, 4, ...] using list comprehension
            favorites = [ row['id'] for row in rows ]
        ctx = {'ad_list' : ad_list, 'favorites': favorites}
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)

    def get(self, request) :
        strval =  request.GET.get("search", False)
        if strval :
            # Simple title-only search
            # objects = Post.objects.filter(title__contains=strval).select_related().order_by('-updated_at')[:10]

            # Multi-field search
            # __icontains for case-insensitive search
            query = Q(title__icontains=strval)
            query.add(Q(text__icontains=strval), Q.OR)
            objects = Ad.objects.filter(query).select_related().order_by('-updated_at')[:10]
        else :
            objects = Ad.objects.all().order_by('-updated_at')[:10]

        # Augment the post_list
        for obj in objects:
            obj.natural_updated = naturaltime(obj.updated_at)

        ctx = {'ad_list' : objects, 'search': strval}
        retval = render(request, self.template_name, ctx)

        dump_queries()
        return retval
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to have two get() functions. just combine these codes and make one get() function.

```
def get(self, request):
    favorites = list()
    strval = request.GET.get("search", False)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # rows = [{'id': 2}, {'id': 4} ... ]  (A list of rows)
        rows = request.user.favorite_ads.values('id')
        # favorites = [2, 4, ...] using list comprehension
        favorites = [row['id'] for row in rows]

    if strval:
        query = Q(title__icontains=strval)
        query.add(Q(text__icontains=strval), Q.OR)
        ad_list = Ad.objects.filter(query).select_related().order_by(
            '-updated_at')[:10]
    else:
        ad_list = Ad.objects.all().order_by('-updated_at')[:10]

    # Augment the ad_list
    for obj in ad_list:
        obj.natural_updated = naturaltime(obj.updated_at)

    ctx = {'ad_list': ad_list, 'favorites': favorites}
    return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)
```